# Condition on Datatables or where database and Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, datatable

I have a laravel project, I want to create condition if or where database if user login have my id, then to show the main content is created.

this is my javascript on my View

```
    <script>
  $('#dataTable').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: '{{ route('api.row_cosos') }}',    
    columns: [
    { data: 'cosos.id'},
    { data: 'tencoso' },   
    { data: 'chucoso'},   
    { data: 'dkkd'},
    { data: 'diachi'},
    { data: 'sdt'},     
    { data: 'name'}, 
    { data: 'ghichu'},
    { data: 'created_at'},
    { data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false }
    ],    
});
</script>
```

this is my api.row_cosos on my Controller

Option 1: This is way to create with where('users.id', '=', 1) --> Success

```
public function getCososData()
    {      
        $cosos = DB::table('cosos')
        ->join('users', 'cosos.quanly_id', '=', 'users.id')            
        ->select('cosos.id', 'cosos.tencoso','cosos.chucoso','cosos.dkkd','cosos.sdt','cosos.ghichu','cosos.diachi','users.name','cosos.created_at','cosos.updated_at') 
        ->where('users.id', '=', 1) 
        ->get();
    return Datatables::of($cosos)        
    ->addColumn('action', function ($cosos) {
        return '<a href="/admin/cosos/'. $cosos->id.'/edit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Sửa</a> <a href="/admin/delete-coso/" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Xóa</a>';
    })
    ->editColumn('cosos.id', '{{$id}}')
    ->removeColumn('cosos.updated_at')
    ->setRowId('cosos.id')
    ->setRowClass(function ($coso) {
        return $coso->id % 2 == 0 ? 'alert-success' : 'alert-warning';
    })
    ->setRowData([
        'cosos.id' => 'test',
    ])
    ->setRowAttr([
        'color' => 'red',
    ])
    ->make(true);
}
```

Option 2: This is way to create with where('users.id', '=', Auth:id()) and I login with user id = 1--> Error no data

```
public function getCososData()
        {      
            $cosos = DB::table('cosos')
            ->join('users', 'cosos.quanly_id', '=', 'users.id')            
            ->select('cosos.id', 'cosos.tencoso','cosos.chucoso','cosos.dkkd','cosos.sdt','cosos.ghichu','cosos.diachi','users.name','cosos.created_at','cosos.updated_at') 
            ->where('users.id', '=', Auth:id()) 
            ->get();
        return Datatables::of($cosos)        
        ->addColumn('action', function ($cosos) {
            return '<a href="/admin/cosos/'. $cosos->id.'/edit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Sửa</a> <a href="/admin/delete-coso/" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Xóa</a>';
        })
        ->editColumn('cosos.id', '{{$id}}')
        ->removeColumn('cosos.updated_at')
        ->setRowId('cosos.id')
        ->setRowClass(function ($coso) {
            return $coso->id % 2 == 0 ? 'alert-success' : 'alert-warning';
        })
        ->setRowData([
            'cosos.id' => 'test',
        ])
        ->setRowAttr([
            'color' => 'red',
        ])
        ->make(true);
    }
```

Please help me, thank you

Comment: do a `dd(Auth::id())` to ensure the authentication is set up properly

Comment: If use where('users.id', '=', 1) result 
Collection {#580
#items: array:6 [
0 => {#581
+"id": 3
+"tencoso": "Trung tín2"
+"chucoso": "Trung"
+"dkkd": "382742"
+"sdt": 32423
+"ghichu": "432423"
+"diachi": ""
+"name": "Admin"
+"created_at": "2018-10-19 06:03:39"
+"updated_at": "2018-10-21 02:01:16"
}
1 => {#578
}
2 => {#571
}
3 => {#575
..
https://b.f4.photo.talk.zdn.vn/2985281316259084415/2b212322e7a707f95eb6.jpg 
If use where('users.id', '=', Auth::id()) result 
Collection {#580
  #items: []
}
https://b.f4.photo.talk.zdn.vn/3155055521449199847/4f41514295c775992cd6.jpg

Comment: that means `Auth::id()` is not 1

Comment: If I run function do not use Datatable then result success. I think problem in the Datatable

Answer (score 0):

write Auth::user()->id,It will access the user table and point to the id of user table.And you will get the data.

Comment: Auth::user()->id same as Auth::id(), I have the table 'user' link foreign quanly_id on table cosos.

Comment: try by removing '=' sign, Like this ->where('users.id', Auth:id())

Comment: can you send me the error which you are getting in laravel.log file.